# Map `State` via `Lens`

Tags: scala, scalaz, state-monad, lenses, monocle-scala

Is there some function with signature like

```
lensMapState[S, T, A](lens : Lens[S, T]): State[T, A] => State[S, A]
```

With semantics *run modification of chosen part and get result*

One implementation could be

```
def lensMapState[S, T, A](lens: Lens[S, T]): State[T, A] => State[S, A] =
    stateT => State { s =>
      val (result, x) = stateT.run(lens.get(s))
      (lens.set(result)(s), x)
    }
```

but if there more straightforward way using [monocle](https://github.com/julien-truffaut/Monocle) or [scalaz.Lens](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/nightly/index.html#scalaz.LensFamily) ?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
case object Person {
  val _age = Lens.lensu[Person, Int]((p, a) => p.copy(age = a), _.age 
}

val state = for {
  a <- Person._age %= { _ + 1 } 
} yield a

state.run(Person("Holmes", 42))
```

which results in

```
res0: scalaz.Id.Id[(Person, Int)] = (Person(Holmes,43),43)
```

There are many lens/state related functions defined in https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.1.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Lens.scala
Monocle follows a similiar principle. The related functions are defined in monocle.state as far as I know.

Comment: Not quite. I need a mapping from `State[Int, a]`  to `State[Person, a]` while   `%=` is a conversion from `Int -> Int` to `State[Person, Int]`

Comment: Ah, sorry, I did not pay enough attention to your types.

Comment: But I still think that is could lead to something, so +1